# Failed to add users to my organization in DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I have a problem and apparently it happens because before I had my business account registered as a personal account in microsoft. I have already deleted that account to keep the business account only but now when I want to add the account to my organization in DevOps it does not allow me to add it, it tells me that there is an error and already, it does not add it to the organization.

I realized that DevOps tries to add the personal Microsoft account again and not the new one I have (Microsoft 365), I don't know how I can solve that, if they could help me.

The question is also in Developer Community in Microsoft: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1096647/no-puedo-unirme-a-una-organizacion-en-devops.html

Comment: Go to https://aex.dev.azure.com/me check whether there is option of Microsoft Account in dropdownlist box. On the other hand, does it ask you to choose personal or work account during login?

Comment: I checked these DevOps organizations, one is connected to Azure AD, so it uses work account and you can access it. Another is not connected to Azure AD and your account is recognized as Microsoft account. You can connect this DevOps organization to Azure AD too, then you should be able to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue with these steps below:

1. Sign out the account and close the browser.
2. Please ask your Project Collection Admins (PCA) to delete and re-add the account in the organization.
3. Don't click the email link or use the normal browser window to access the organization.
4. Firstly, please open an InPrivate/incognito browser window. Then, you could access to "https://dev.azure.com/TCI-Software" directly in the InPrivate/incognito browser window.